# Very Simple login HTML5

Tags: html, authentication

I'm trying to make the simplest of logins. Simply need to have a 1 static username/password to proceed to next html page in my directory via button click.

I've tried using this method but doesn't seem to work for me.

```
<input type="text" name="login" required pattern="user123">
<input type="text" name="password" required pattern="password1234">
```

Any ideas would be helpful. Heres the full login if it helps http://jsfiddle.net/aHzAP/

Comment: What did you expect this to do?  You need to connect your form to a backend of some kind that authenticates the user's credentials.  Just throwing a couple form fields onto a page is not going to produce a working login.  How did you think it was going to determine the whether or not the user submitted a valid username and password?

Comment: I'm lost for words. You've tagged your question with `html5`, yet you're using tables for layout, `<center>` tags and `<font>` tags

Comment: Argh argh argh `<font>`. But (one) problem is that you're circumventing the native validation with the redirection in the onclick attribute. Why have it at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to the question is that the asker wants the user name and password to be static.

Why not use very simple Javascript to do this?

```
    <input type="text" id="login" required>
    <input type="text" id="password" required>
    <input type="button" id="goButton" onclick="checkLoginPass()" />
    <script>
        var checkLoginPass = function () {
            var login = document.getElementById("login").value;
            var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
            if (login === "user123" && pass === "password1234") {
                window.location.replace("http://www.someurlhere.com");
            }
            else {
                //do something else;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Have you learned nothing from the question you 'borrowed' this code from? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19575763/very-simple-js-static-login/19575826#19575826

Comment: my answer was posted before this question was asked...  I think the 'borrowing' is the other way around here...

Comment: Oh lol I see. I just thought it was funny because I was just coming from that question.

Comment: Lol, it's ok.  The original asker decided to post a whole new question instead of just adding a comment and asking why it wasn't working...  At least they found the solution they were looking for, that's all that really matters... and thanks for the correction on the location.replace, i got really close without any testing :)

Answer (score 0):

Your  should have an action and a method attribute, onclick won't send any information to the pages it will lead when clicked

```
<form action="AdminResults.php" method="post">
```

Edit: You will need something like php on the action page to check if the authentication is valid