# Very simple js static login

Tags: javascript, html, authentication

Just trying to get a very simple js login to validate a static username/password however cant seem to get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
var checkLoginPass = function () {
    var login = document.getElementById("login").value;
    var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
    if (login === "user123" && pass === "password1234") {
        window.location("http://www.google.com");
    }
    else {
        //do something else;
    }
};
```

```htmll
<input type="text" id="login" required>
<input type="text" id="password" required>
<input type="button" id="goButton" onclick="checkLoginPass()" value="Log In"/>
```

Comment: `window.location` isn’t a function; I think you probably meant to set it. (And read the error message.)

Comment: I hope you are aware that this offers **no security whatsoever**, since anyone can look at the source code and read the username and password. Or just go to the URL themselves to begin with. Just pointing it out...

Comment: @deceze yes. not a full implementing project, just testing purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `location.replace("http://www.google.com");` instead of `window.location("http://www.google.com");`